# Update items in ComboBox after lookup value is added

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a WPF form that contains a DataGrid. This DataGrid is editable. One column of the DataGrid  contains a ComboBox with a list of lookup codes for the user to select from.

While editing, the user can add a new lookup code by calling a modal window. When control is returned to the DataGrid, the combobox does not have the new lookupcode.

How can I refresh the list in the combobox after an item is added?

Here is how my combobox is defined. Below is the column of the DataGrid and then my dictionary snippet.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Width="160">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AddrType.Description}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox Name="cboAddrtype" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource addrTypeList}}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="ID" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding AddrTypeID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      Width="100" />
            <Button ToolTip="New" Name="btnNewAddressType" Click="btnNewAddressType_Click">
                <Image Source="Images\Add.png" Style="{StaticResource buttonImageStyle}" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

The method GetAddressTypes() returns an ObservableCollection.

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="addrTypeList" IsAsynchronous="True"
                    MethodName="GetAddressTypes"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type components:AddressComponent}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the new address to the addrtypeList when the modal window is closed, or the object saved depending on your desired behavior.  Because its an observableCollection it should update the combo box automatically.